# creating camel module for jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x, apache-camel

In module.xml file in Jboss AS 7, I have a dependency

```
    <dependencies> 
    <module name="org.apache.camel.components"/>            
    </dependencies>
```

I dont know what are the camel jar files I must include in the folder path org/apache/camel/components/main/ .

Kindly guide me

Comment: Your dependency is referencing "components" which is the top level package for ALL Camel components.  Was there a specific one you were wanting to use?

Answer (score 1):

to start, you need camel-core...possibly others depending on which [components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) you need...

download here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core

or if you are using Maven, just add this dependency to your project's pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```